# How update all packages in Oracle Linux 7.5?

Tags: yum, repository, oracle-linux

How could be possible to update all yum repositories in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory?
Is this command is right for this purpose?

`yum update repolist`
or
`yum repolist all`

Comment: what do you mean with "update all yum repositories"? What's the thing you want to achieve?

Comment: Ditto above; also, what does Oracle Linux (tag) have to do with this?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, How can I update all packages in centos? `yum update` is enough? what does `yum repolist all` do then?
I don't know in Linux, we can update packages or repositories? or both?!

Comment: @JeffSchaller, Actually the linux distribution that is installed is `Oracle linux 7.5`. that's why I mentioned it in tags.

Answer (score 1):

`yum update` updates all packages.

`yum repolist` (as `yum help` tells you),  will

> display the configured software repositories